# Enums: Retrieve enum value from enumeration name string

Tags: c#, enums

The enum:

```
public enum EnumName
{
    Gary = 1,
    Dave = 2
}
```

The input:

```
string inputValue = "Gary";
```

What is the best way to retrieve the value from the enum for this string? I.e. return the value 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Enum.Parse` to convert a string to an enum, or `Enum.TryParse` if you are less sure of the input.

```
(EnumName)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumName), inputValue)
```

You can convert any enum to its underlying type, the default is int if unspecified, by casting. Like this :

```
(int)Enum.Parse(typeof(EnumName), inputValue)
```

Comment: This gives an enum with value "Gary". The thing I'm not understanding though is how to then succinctly retrieve the integer 1.

Comment: I've edited the answer to answer your question.